# Contar los caracteres javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente objetivo: Escribe una función en `JavaScript` llamada **contar** que reciba dos parámetros: **texto** y **carácter**. La función debe retornar el número de veces que aparece **carácter** en **texto**.

```
contar("Hello", "l"); // retorna 2
contar("Hola", "g");  // retorna 0
```

Como puedo hacer para que me traiga el valor exacto de las veces que se repite el carácter? Algún método diferente que me pueda servir?

Mi código:

```
function contar (texto, caracter){
   var cont = 0;
     for(var i=0; i<texto.length; i++){
         if (texto[i] == caracter){
         cont = cont + 1;
     console.log(cont);
    //return (cont);
    }
  }
}
contar ("mañana" "a");
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu código esta prácticamente bien, a excepción de unas cosas.

El `return` que tienes comentado lo debes poner fuera del bucle `for`, para asignar su valor su quieres a una variable.

y en la llamada de tu función te falta poner la coma para separar los parámetros.

```
contar ("mañana" ,'a');
```

Código completo:

```
function contar (texto, caracter){
   var cont = 0;
   for(var i=0; i<texto.length; i++){
      if (texto[i] == caracter){
          cont = cont + 1;
          console.log(cont);
      }
   }
   return (cont);
}

contar ("mañana" ,'a');
```

Ejemplo para asignar el valor de tu función utilizando el `return` a una variable:

```
var resultado = contar ("mañana" ,'a'); 
console.log(resultado);// Da como resultado 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Aqui propongo un codigo mas corto para resolver esta cuestión:

```
function contar(texto, caracter) {
  return [...texto].filter(l => l === caracter).length;
}
let resultado = contar("mañana", "a");
console.log('Resultado: ' + resultado);
```